# Confusion about binary expansion of number in $(0,1)$.

Tags: binary, binary-operations

Unfamiliar with discrete mathematics, I wondered in the following two answers [Fast way to find period-n points of a tent map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048525/fast-way-to-find-period-n-points-of-a-tent-map)

[Techniques for finding period points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948090/techniques-for-finding-period-points)

, why the authors  wrote:

1.

> "Every real number $x$ in $[0,1]$ can be written (almost) uniquely as $$x=\frac12-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}b_n(x)$$ where, for each $n\geqslant1$, $b_n(x)$ is either $+1$ or $-1$.
> "

2. 

> " After a bit of head-scratching, one may get the idea of using a slightly different expansion of every $x$ in $[0,1]$, namely, $$x=\frac12+\frac12\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{s_n(x)}{2^n},\qquad s_n(x)\in\{-1,1\}.$$
> "

I apologize if the question was previously asked (I also apologize for the title if it does not faithfully reflect the question).

Many thanks for any help with this!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why the authors wrote two different binary expansions for the same number.

Comment: Binary representations of real numbers need not be unique unlike binary representations of natural numbers.

Comment: The only difference here is that one chose to have a subtraction in front instead of an addition. As a result, for all $n, s_n(x) = -b_n(x)$. Effectively they are the same representation. FYI - these are not exactly "binary expansions", since that terminology refers to using $0$ and $1$ as the bits, not $1$ and $-1$.